# No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/usr/logs/' for main error log AH00014: Configuration check failed

Tags: php, bash, apache, macos-sierra

I am trying to install and configure PHP 7.2 on my MacOS Sierra. After installation, I failed to start Apache server and getting following errors.

```
No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/usr/logs/' for main error log
AH00014: Configuration check failed
```

I also tried to create '/usr/logs/' directory but it is not permitted. 
Commands I am using:

```
$sudo apachectl start
$apachectl configtest
```

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache needs write permissions for logs:

On osx /usr is a protected directory, system does not allow creating subdirs in it manually.

- Create directory /logs `sudo mkdir /logs`
- Set permissions `sudo chmod 775 /logs`
- Set owner `sudo chown {your-apache-user}:{your-apache-group} /logs`
- Optionaly you can add apache user to group of current dir owner (this would be a more universal and cleaner solution) instead of making apache the owner
- In apache config (dont forget vhosts), change the log directory to 
  the onew directory
- restart apache

Much better option: use Vagrant https://www.vagrantup.com/ , that way you wont trash your OS

Comment: When I tried to create directory, I get following error. "mkdir: /usr/logs: Operation not permitted"

Comment: use `sudo` before the command. This is system owned directory so you need elevated privilege to write

Comment: hmmm... check if the directory /usr/logs already exists? if it does, you will need to add apache user to the dir owner group

Comment: It does not exists

Comment: In that case create a new directory, lets say /logs. then change apache config to use that directory. Don't forget to change owner of directory and access permissions so that apache can write there

Comment: Doesn't work here with Manjaro. I even set apache user to my user, but still no luck. Tbh. I would rather use a different server application.

Answer (score 5):

A complete and satisfactory solution is also given at https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214527565-Unable-to-start-Apache-when-Apache-logs-directory-is-missing-No-such-file-or-directory-Unable-to-open-logs:

If the error message is

> Starting httpd: (2)No such file or directory: httpd: could not open error log file /etc/httpd/logs/error_log.
>   Unable to open logs

or

> httpd[26817]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 43 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf:
>   httpd[26817]: ModSecurity: Failed to open debug log file: /var/log/httpd/modsec_debug.log

or

> [error] (2)No such file or directory: mod_jk: could not open JkLog file /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
>   Configuration Failed

or even

> apachectl[1891]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for main error log
>   apachectl[1891]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1

Then running (as root):

```
mkdir /var/log/httpd
chmod 700 /var/log/httpd/
service httpd start
```

or

```
mkdir /var/log/apache2
chmod 750 /var/log/apache2
chown root:adm /var/log/apache2
 service apache2 start
```

should do it!